# Mutate functions on the neighborhood of a node in Tidygraph without a map

Tags: r, dplyr, igraph, purrr, tidygraph

I have a graph, with an attribute `W`. I want to `mutate` the average `W` of the neighbors. I want to keep the code as simple as possible, trying to avoid `maps` and other explicit functions for vectorisation, because this is for didactic purposes.

My code, trying to show well each passage would look like this:

```
set.seed(1810)

create_ring(40) %>%
  mutate(id = row_number()) -> ring

ring %>%
      mutate(W = rnorm(40,75,15)) %>%
      mutate(Neighs = local_members(order = 1,
                                    mindist = 1),
             k = local_size(order = 1,
                            mindist = 1)) -> ring
    
ring %>%
  mutate(
    W_neighs = map_dbl(
      Neighs,
      function(x) mean(W[id %in% unlist(x)])
    )
  )
```

Is there a way to perform these operations without recurring to `map`? Tidygraph has a similar wrapper that is `local_ave_degree`, that wraps `igraph::knn`, that wraps something in C...

Also, I would be interested in an explanation if `morph` can be useful for these operations.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use `ego` from `igraph` to save a lot of lines (no need to create the columns `Neighs` or `k`), e.g.,

```
set.seed(1810)

ring <- create_ring(40) %>%
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>%
  mutate(W = rnorm(40, 75, 15)) %>%
  mutate(W_neighs = 
    as.igraph(.) %>%
      ego(order = 1, mindist = 1) %>%
      sapply(function(v) mean(v$W))
  )
```

and you will see

```
> ring
# A tbl_graph: 40 nodes and 40 edges
#
# An undirected simple graph with 1 component
#
# Node Data: 40 × 3 (active)
     id     W W_neighs
  <int> <dbl>    <dbl>
1     1  84.3     96.1
2     2  84.5     91.9
3     3  99.4     91.2
4     4  97.9     67.9
5     5  36.4     89.4
6     6  80.8     51.2
# … with 34 more rows
#
# Edge Data: 40 × 2
   from    to
  <int> <int>
1     1     2
2     2     3
3     3     4
# … with 37 more rows
```

Comment: I am not sure that I want to use a function from igraph in a lecture on tidygraph. I want those columns because students have to understand what's happening. Students have always a poor understanding of maps and applies. This is why I wanted to avoid them.

Comment: @GiulioGCantone If you don't want `igraph`, I suggest you remove the `igraph` tag under your post to avoid confusion. BTW, what is your ultimate goal? If you want to avoid `map` or `*apply`, you could use `for` loop instead, but it seems you are after something else ....